# Video mediaDevices Assign a Blob To 'videoRef.srcObject' In Place of 'src'

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc, recordrtc

I am trying to make a blob the src of a video element. My code is working fine when:

```
videoRef.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

but using 'src' and 'URL.createObjectURL' is deprecated in place of using 'srcObject' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

[image]

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

[image]

My question is how can I simply add a blob file to the srcObject like so:

```
videoRef.srcObject = blob
```

When I try the above code I get the error: "TypeError: Failed to set the 'srcObject' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The provided value is not of type 'MediaStream'."

How can I not use the deprecated videoRef.src and apply a blob directly to videoRef.srcObject ? Or is it ok for blob type to use src, and only streams can't use src ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`URL.createObjectURL` is only deprecated for ***streams***, not blobs and mediasources.

The MDN warning you reference is under the section titled [Using object URLs for media streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Usage_notes). The warning itself says:

> If you still have code that relies on createObjectURL() to attach ***streams*** to media elements

There's an effort to deprecate `URL.createObjectURL` specifically around ***streams***, because streams are inherently local objects.

> TypeError: Failed to set the 'srcObject' property on 'HTMLMediaElement

Looks like your browser hasn't implemented `srcObject` for blobs yet. This is common atm.

E.g. both Chrome and Firefox have [partial support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/wBV5TNDEziU) for srcObject for streams only, but not blob, file, or mediasource.

MDN on [srcObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject) echoes this:

> As of November 2017, browsers only support MediaStream. For MediaSource, Blob and File, you have to create a URL with URL.createObjectURL() and assign it to HTMLMediaElement.src.

Comment: URL.createObjectURL is only deprecated for streams ... Awesome response. Thank you!

Comment: But here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject they give an example with `MediaSource` and a comment "Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away" for the `createObjectURL` option. This is confusing.

Comment: @AlexanderZinchuk You're right, that [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject#Examples) was confusing, so I've updated it. PTAL!

Comment: I love you and want you to have my children

Answer (score 2):

Just adding my recent 'fun' experience with Safari on iOS and MacOS here. I finally figured out that the latest versions need a bit more love to get blob videos to play back, namely the use of the new video.srcObject (not .src) needing to be provided with a new Blob that includes type information about the video being played. Eg:

```
var fileInfo = {type: "video/mp4"}
video.srcObject = new Blob([blob], fileInfo);
```

Using the basic structure from another post the following code worked for me:

```
function setVideoFromBlob(blob, fileInfo = {type: "video/mp4"}) {
    // Older browsers may not have srcObject
    if ('srcObject' in video) {
        try {
           //fileInfo (type) required by safari, but not by chrome..
           video.srcObject = new Blob([blob], fileInfo);
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.name != "TypeError") {
                throw err;
            }
            // Even if they do, they may only support MediaStream
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        }
    } else {
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps some people out.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to jib's answer, here's a code snippet from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject#Supporting_fallback_to_the_src_property) detailing a fallback for supporting older browsers:

```
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
const video = document.createElement('video');
try {
  video.srcObject = mediaSource;
} catch (error) {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
}
```