# Why does MediaRecorder show up blank on Firefox but not on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

I've written a small javascript application that uses the mouse to draw lines on a canvas, captures that stream, and then creates a video. After that video is created, it attaches it to a `<video>` tag.

When I run this on Chrome, it runs completely fine.

When I run this on Firefox, it returns a completely black video. The time length of the video is correct though.

More bizarrely, when I save the video from Chrome (via right-click and "save video as..."), the file it saves to shows up as completely black.

I attempted to stream the video as I drew to see if the issue had to do with the `.captureStream()` function. That works fine however. My gut tells me the issue is from the MediaRecorder format but I'm not 100% certain as I confirmed that firefox supports this video format with `` MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(`video/webm;codecs=vp8`) ``

I'm running Firefox 78.0.2 under Ubuntu 18.04. Code is below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid black;
      cursor: crosshair;
    }

    .canvas-holder {
      width: 40%;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .video-holder {
      width: 40%;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas-holder">
      <canvas id="mycanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
      <button id="save-button">Save Canvas</button>
      <button id="start-button">Start Recording</button>
      <button id="stop-button">Stop Recording</button>
    </div>
    <div class="video-holder">
      <video id="stream-video" width="300" height="300"></video>
      <video id="myvideo" width="300" height="300"></video>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas#mycanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 1; // helps with jagged edges
    ctx.shadowColor = "black";

    // drawing logic
    mouse = { x: 0, y: 0, moveflag: false };

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", e => draw("mousedown", e), false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => draw("mousemove", e), false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", e => draw("mouseup", e), false);

    function draw(res, e) {
      if (res == "mousedown") {
        // begin drawing
        mouse.moveflag = true;
      } else if (res == "mousemove" && mouse.moveflag) {
        mouse.x = e.offsetX; // this compensates for the canvas being slightly off
        mouse.y = e.offsetY;
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.stroke();
      } else if (res == "mouseup" && mouse) {
        mouse.moveflag = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
      } else {
        return;
      }
    }

    // saving logic
    saveButton = document.querySelector("#save-button");
    saveButton.onclick = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log("saved!");
      var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      // window.location.href = image;  // redirect to saved image
      console.log("Image, base64 encoded =>  ", image);
    };

    // video logic
    const videoTag = document.querySelector("video#myvideo");
    const streamVideo = document.querySelector("video#stream-video");
    const startButton = document.querySelector("button#start-button");
    const stopButton = document.querySelector("button#stop-button");
    const stream = canvas.captureStream();
    streamVideo.srcObject = stream;

    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
      mimeType: `video/webm;codecs=vp8`
    });

    let chunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => {
      console.log("chunking data");
      chunks.push(e.data);
    };
    mediaRecorder.onstop = e => {
      console.log("stopping mediaRecorder");
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
        type: `video/webm;codecs=vp8`
      });

      // create a local URL and set the video to that
      // its all black!
      const videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      videoTag.src = videoURL;
      videoTag.play();
    };

    startButton.onclick = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      mediaRecorder.start();
      console.log("start recording");
    };
    stopButton.onclick = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      console.log("stop recording");
    };
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Firefox dropped support for [setting video.src from URL.createObjectURL](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2017/url-createobjecturl-stream-has-been-deprecated/), instead you must set the [stream to the video.srcObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669528/video-mediadevices-assign-a-blob-to-videoref-srcobject-in-place-of-src). Currently in Firefox you cannot set MediaSource, Blob and File to video.srcObject, only [MediaStream is supported.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject)

Comment: Can I still use MediaRecorder to record the canvas here?