# Unable to Playback MediaRecorder Blobs Streamed over WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, web-mediarecorder

I am unable to get blobs recorded by an instance of `MediaRecorder` that are sent over WebSocket to playback on the client machine's `video` element. Here is an excerpt of my code:

sender.js:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
  video: {
      facingMode: 'user'
  },
  audio = true
}).then((stream) => {
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    recorder.ondataavailable((event) => {
        socket.send(event.data); // according to the client console, THIS SENDS A BLOB!!!
    });
    recorder.start(1000);
});
```

receiver.js:

```
socket.onmessage = (message) => {
    console.log(message.data); // instanceof Blob
    blob = message.data;
    // tried this  answer but it still does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72772924/1079320
    blob = new Blob([message.data], { // the Blob.type attribute is ignored when sent by WebSocket: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/send
        type: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'
    });
    // blob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'); // this answer does not work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50875615/1079320
    video.srcObject = blob; // under "Usage notes" from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject the URL.createObjectUrl() method is no longer needed!
    video.play(); // const video = document.getElementById('video-element-id');
};
```

I get no errors, but the video element simply does not play. Testing using the Firefox browser.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally figured it out: The key was to use the `MediaSource` API. Example code can be found under "Examples" here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource/MediaSource

Firstly, it is important to note that I couldn't make this code work within the `body.onload` listener I was using before: Instead, I had to put the `<script>` tag directly in the `<body>` of the HTML document itself.

Furthermore, I had to pass the raw `Blob` contents as an `arrayBuffer` using the `blob.arrayBuffer()` promise.

That said, here is the revised version of my code:

receiver.js:

```
let mediaSource = new MediaSource;
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource); // const video = document.getElementById('video-element-id');
let sourceBuffer;

socket.onmessage = (message) => {
    console.log(message.data); // remember, this is instanceof Blob
    if (!sourceBuffer) {
        sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/webm');
        video.play();
    }
    message.data.arrayBuffer().then((arrayBuffer) => {
        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
    });
};
```

And ***BAH-BAM!*** Everything is working as it should now.

Thanks to "guest271314" for suggesting I look into `MediaSource`.

Answer (score 0):

`recorder.ondataavailable(event => {`  should be `recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {}` or `recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {})`. If `message.data` is a `Blob` and not an `ArrayBuffer` you don't have to create a new `Blob`, just use the `Blob` defined on the `event`. Additionally, `Blob` set as `src` won't work. You are not setting a `MediaStream` to `srcObject`. Pass the `Blob` to `URL.createObjectURL()` then set the Blob URL as the `HTMLMediaElement` `src`.

```
socket.onmessage = (message) => {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(message.data);
  video.play(); 
};
```

Comment: Not the case according to:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject

Under "Usage notes": 
 
"Older versions of the Media Source specification required using URL.createObjectURL() to create an object URL then setting src to that URL. Now you can just set srcObject to the MediaStream directly."

Comment: Where is a `MediaSource` or `MediaStream` mentioned in OP? You are not getting a `MediaStream` from `WebSocket` message handler, you are getting a `Blob` or an `ArrayBuffer`. There are probably other issues you will encounter if you are not sending back the entire `Blob` in one message, because for WebM container produced by `MediaRecorder` only the first `Blob` from `dataavailable` event will contain metadata. So all of the `Blob`s you send after the first when using `start()` will not be playable by `HTMLMediaElement` - at least not without some additional extraction of data and processing.

Comment: The `getUserMedia()` method returns a promise that receives a `MediaStream` object: 
 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Right, but you are not setting that `MediaStream` at `srcObject` of an `HTMLMediaElement`. You are sending `Blob`s to a remote `WebSocket` server and getting a `Blob` or multiple `Blob`s back. Are you trying to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38842623/?

Comment: Odd: I can get the `MediaStream` object to playback from within the closure of the `getUserMedia` promise simply by calling `video.srcObject = stream`.

Comment: Yes, but you are not doing that in the code at OP. You are sending multiple `Blob`s to a `WebSocket` server and getting one or more `Blob` back. That is, you are not getting a `MediaStream` back from WebSocket `message` handler. Note, technically it is possible to create a `MediaStreamTrack` from images using either `canvas.captureStream()` or `MediaStreamTrackGenerator`.  How many times is the `WebSocket` `message` event handler dispatched?

Comment: I know that I'm sending a Blob: I said as much in my title and comments. The content-type/mime type attribute of the Blob object is ignored when sending over WebSocket. That's where I'm stuck!

Comment: `type` of `Blob` sent to `WebSocket` server shouldn't matter as long as you set that `type` when you pass the `Blob` to `URL.createObjectURL()`; for that you might need to create a new `Blob` just to set `type`. Why are you using `MediaRecorder`s `start()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257245/discussion-between-lincolnberryiii-and-guest271314).